# Append query string to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a callback url string `params[:callback]` and I need to append a query string `"&result=true"` and redirect the user. The better way I found of doing this is using `addressable` but I think the code is too big for task like this especially when we are talking about ruby:

```
callback = Addressable::URI.parse(params[:callback])
query = callback.query_values
query[:result] = 'true'
callback.query_values = query

redirect_to callback.to_s
```

Is there a more elegant way of getting the same result as this snippet?

Answer (score 15):

I wan't to bring update to this topic, because any of the solutions didn't work me.

The reason being, that it seems that `callback.query_values` returns `Nil` if the actual url doesn't have existing query values.

Therefore if you have urls such as: `http://www.foo.com` and `http://www.foo.com?bar=1` you should use the following code:

```
url = "http://www.foo.com" # or params[:callback] obviously. :)

callback = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
callback.query_values = (callback.query_values || {}).merge({
  result: true
})

redirect_to callback.to_s
```

Cheers.

Comment: I just want to add that If the param may already exist make sure that `"result"` is a string, not a symbol `:result` so you don't get a double param like "http://www.foo.com?result=true&result=true" or "http://www.foo.com?result=true&result=false". Also if true is a boolean `result: true` and not a string `result: "true"` this can raise an `ArgumentError (comparison of Array with Array failed)`

Answer (score 9):

- if you don't need any URL validations you can do this (looks a little bit dirty):

  ```
  url = params[:callback]
  redirect_to url + (url.include?('?') ? '&' : '?') + 'result=true'
  ```
- otherwise you have to use either some external library (like Addressable) or URI module from standard library

Comment: yeah, it looks dirty. Looking at my code using Addressable is there anyway this code could be shorter ?

Answer (score 3):

```
callback.query_values = callback.query_values.merge({"result" => "true"})
```

Comment: Mauna's answer below is better because `callback.query_values` can return `nil`, which does not respond to `merge`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close to optimal.  you could crush out a line or two,
but it doesn't really gain you anything.

```
callback = Addressable::URI.parse(params[:callback])
callback.query_values = callback.query_values.merge {:results => 'true' }
redirect_to callback.to_s
```

If the callback is always inside your application, you might have some other options with varying degrees of coolness, but you didn't specify if that was the case or not.

Answer (score 0):

years later, I find a better solution of this problem.

Get the value from the `super` first, then do any tweaks we need using `Addressable`

```
def url_for(options={})
  val = super

  if params[:locale].present?
    parsed = Addressable::URI.parse(val)
    query_array = parsed.query_values(Array) || []
    query_array << ['locale', params[:locale]]
    parsed.query_values = query_array
    val = parsed.to_s
  end

  val
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me offer this one modestly. I suggest using only strings for query parameters keys and values (like Arye noted) . Also, `NilClass` instances have a `to_h` method, which allows to remove some brackets:

```
callback = Addressable::URI.parse(params[:callback])

callback.query_values = callback.query_values.to_h.merge("result" => "true")

redirect_to callback.to_s
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try with `merge`

`request.parameters.merge({:result => true})`

this will add your parameter to the ones already defined.

Comment: OP has the URL in a variable. It's not the current request URL