# Rails 5 Query from url address with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How I can generate an URL with query

for example `http://localhost:3000/articles`

what I want is, this URL can be load with query

e.g. `articles?author="author_name"`

what should I do in my controller?

edit: article_controller

```
def index
@articles = Article.all
end
```

routes

```
resources :authors
resources :articles
resources :categories
```

view

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= article.no_urut %></td>
    <td><%= article.judul_artikel %></td>
    <td><%= article.konten %></td>
    <td><%= article.category.nama_kategori %></td>
    <td><%= article.author.author_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', article %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561953/2231236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ray said, if you add:

```
<%= link_to articles_path(author: "name_here") %>
```

that will generate the url `http://localhost:3000/articles?author=name_here`

You may find it easier to use a gem to easily implement a search for articles by author name but if you just want to do this manually in your ArticlesController:

```
def index
  if params[:author]
    @author = params[:author]
    @articles = Article.all.where(author: @author)
  else
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need do anything in controller as `articles_path` rails url path will route to `http://localhost:3000/articles` (provided with proper routes)

So passing any key value will be okay with `articles_path(author: 'author_name')` and access it in controller action as `params[:author_name]`

**Update:** If you want to get authors in index by providing name it is search function & can be done efficiently with [ranksack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

Please refer [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) to see resulting view

Comment: but the view what I expected is articles#index showing only the author that I call in URL

Comment: I cannot predict without processing url in log, action and routes you defined

Comment: Check updated answer, you can do it more efficiently.

Comment: Thx. But if the URL is json formatted. Just like this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=1

Comment: You can't really put a JSON formatting in the url. The contents of the url can. At your example it would just be `params[:id]`, provided you have proper routes.

Comment: If it like this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1&id=5